# Multiprocessing issue in with python

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, pathos

I am new to multiprocessing in python and have run into some issues with Pool:
OS: Mac Monterey M1 chip Python 3.9.12

in module.py:
I have tried

```
def foo(x)
...
return y
pool = mp.Pool(8)
results = pool.map_async(foo, args)
```

also tried pathos:

```
def foo(x)
...
return y
pool = ProcessPool(8)
results = pool.amap(foo, args)
```

in main script:

```
import module

def main():
   test = module.foo(x)

if __name__ == "__main__":
   main()
```

I also installed the package to local using setup.py.

current error message including:
for multiprocessing

```
AttributeError: Can't pickle local object 'search.<locals>.foo
```

and for pathos

```
TypeError: no default __reduce__ due to non-trivial __cinit__
```

P.S.:
I am new to stackoverflow. I am trying my best to state the problems. I am not sure what information might need to solve the problem. I have been updating the problem every time people asking for new information as soon as I can. So please be polite.

Comment: Do you have ```__name__ == "__main__"```, its [needed](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, thanks for your question. To help users develop solutions, can you please share some of the specific errors that you say "pickle or dill when processing function too"?

Comment: @jwal I am using multiprocessing inside a function under a module file. I am not sure how I can add  `__name__ == "__main__"`  in the module file

Comment: since you don't want to give anyone any information about the problem that you are facing, you should look for a tutorial about "python multiprocessing on windows" , you should find plenty of information in any of them.

Comment: @Vin `AttributeError: Can't pickle local object 'search.<locals>.foo'` for multiprocessing and `TypeError: no default __reduce__ due to non-trivial __cinit__` for pathos

Comment: Hi @Fshi, please update your question to include this error information. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

I'm the author of `dill`, `pathos`, and `multiprocess`. It looks like you have an object that won't serialize.  Your question doesn't provide enough information for me to give you a solution that I know will work -- but I can give you some things to try.

1. Try a different serialization variant in `dill`:

```
    Python 3.7.15 (default, Oct 12 2022, 04:11:53) 
    [Clang 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.4)] on darwin
    Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
    >>> import dill
    >>> dill.settings['recurse'] = True
```

The above will change how objects in the global namespace are handled, so if the function you are interested in passing serializes ok, but there's a unserializable object in the global dict... then the change to the above serialization variant may avoid the "bad" object.  You could also identify the object that's causing the failure, and delete it from your current namespace.  However, if it's needed by the function you are interested in, then you alternately need to refactor the code.

2. Refactor the code, likely to include a `__reduce__` method, or similar (e.g. set/get state methods).

See the [`__reduce__` docs in `pickle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#object.__reduce__). The error you are seeing from `pathos` tells me that you are running in to an object that is written in C (it has a `__cinit__`) and thus needs some additional methods to tell `pickle` or `dill` how to save its state. The problem you might have here is that you didn't create the object in question, and it comes from some module you are importing. This leads to case #3, but without details on your code, I can't say much more.